# Notation for dot product and scalar multiplication in a geometric interpretation of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and assuming $x \neq 0$, my textbook says that $y$ can be written as

$ y = \frac{x}{\|x\|} (\frac{x}{\|x\|}.y) + (y-\frac{x}{\|x\|} (\frac{x}{\|x\|}.y))$

where ${\|x\|}$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$.

As far as I understand, the notation $\frac{x}{\|x\|}.y$ represents the dot product of the vectors $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $y$, which is some real number $d$. The expression $\frac{x}{\|x\|}.y$ is written inside brackets, which means that the vector $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is being "multiplied" by $d$, but I don't know any function from $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ that defines such a "multiplication".

So what am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $c\in\Bbb R$ and $v\in\Bbb R^n$, both $cv$ and $vc$ (we'd usually write the former) are defined as the $w\in\Bbb R^n$ satisfying $w_i=cv_i$ for $1\le i\le n$.

Comment: Thanks; my confusion resulted from the fact that my textbook never mentions that $vc$ (for $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$) is an acceptable notation for the scalar multiplication.

Comment: @ðulfiqaːr It's a surprising inversion of the usual $cv$ in this context, but the author is no doubt accustomed to [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation), in which it would be [reasonably natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation#Outer_products) to write $|v\rangle\langle v|y\rangle$ for $|v\rangle:=\frac{|x\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert}$. In fact, it simplifies to $\frac{|x\rangle\langle x|y\rangle}{\langle x|x\rangle}$